# What's the probability of getting a full house in poker knowing that your first two cards are 3's?

Tags: probability

I was assigned this question on a probability exam:

> A poker deck has 52 cards. 13 ranks and 4 suits.
> A hand in poker is defined as: 5 cards. "Full house" is defined as: 3
> cards of the same number and 2 cards of the same number (different
> from the first 3). Knowing that your first two cards are 3's (clubs and hearts),
> what is the probability of getting a "full house"?

First I tried to define what were my possible successes.
I decided to ignore the first two cards, since each card draw is an independent event, and I could simply think of the problem as if the deck only had 50 cards.

That leaves me with 3 possible "successes" (i.e getting a "full house"):

1. 3, X, X
2. X, 3, X
3. X, X, 3

Where 3 represents the other 3 and X represents any number (from 1-13) excluding 3.

Later, I tried to find the probability of the first success:

$$\frac{2}{50} \cdot \frac{48}{49} \cdot \frac{3}{48}$$

- 2/50 because it **has** to be any of the two remaining 3's
- 48/49 because it can be any card **except** the remaining three
- 3/48 because it **has** to be the card picked in step 2 and there are 3 remaining in the deck.

For the remaining two successes the same logic applies:

- $\frac{48}{50} \cdot \frac{2}{49} \cdot \frac{3}{48}$
- $\frac{48}{50} \cdot \frac{3}{49} \cdot \frac{2}{48}$

Each one of those multiplications results in: $\frac{3}{1225}$
I then added them up because the total success is the *union* of all of these: $\frac{9}{1225}$. Which roughly equals: $0.0073$

However, it was marked as incorrect. Where are the flaws in my reasoning?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you have described is a "full house".  I have never heard the term "full" to describe a poker hand in my life...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Xander. In spanish some speaking countries it is simply referred to as "full". I was not aware of the difference

Comment: For the last two cases, the first term should be $48/50$. There are two 3s in the deck.

Comment: Thanks, I had mistyped it. Now it has the proper numbers

Comment: What rules are you assuming?  Just a straight five card draw?  Note:  I, too, have never heard the term "full" used this way.  And why do you exclude the draw of three identical non-$3's$?

Comment: I *have* often heard people refer to, say, "Kings full of fives", which would refer to a hand with three Kings and two $5's$.  In your post, for example, you appear to be only considering Threes full of $X's$ though of course that's not what you say you are looking for (in my view, you are improperly omitting $X's$ full of Threes).

Comment: You have omitted a case.  You can also complete a full house via X, X, X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have omitted a case.  You also can complete a full house by drawing X, X, X.  The probability that you fall within this case is $\frac{48}{50} \cdot \frac {3}{49} \cdot \frac {2}{48}$.  Add that product to your previous work and you should get the correct answer, which should be $\frac{12}{1225}$.

Comment: Darn! It was so obvious. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

I think that (in general) it is better to make your first *try* for this type of problem, Combinatorics, rather than probability of events.

So, the probability is

$$\frac{N}{D} ~: ~D = \binom{50}{3},$$

where $~N~$ is the total number of ways of completing the full house, sampling the remaining three cards (out of the 50 cards remaining in the deck), without replacement, where order of selection is deemed irrelevant.

There are two ways of completing the full house:

- x's full of 3's, which signifies that the remaining three cards are all of the same rank. 
  Number of ways is $~\displaystyle 12 \times \binom{4}{3} = 48.$ 
  That is, there are $~12~$ ways of choosing the triplet rank, and then $~4~$ ways of tripling from that rank.
- 3's full of x's, which signifies that the 3's will be the triplet. 
  Number of ways is $~\displaystyle \binom{2}{1} \times 12 \times \binom{4}{2} = 144.$ 
  That is, there are $~2~$ ways of selecting one of the remaining 3's, then $~12~$ ways of choosing the pair rank, and then $~6~$ ways of pairing from that rank.

So, the probability is

$$\frac{48 + 144}{\binom{50}{3}} = \frac{12}{1225}.$$